# Are the two groups $G, G'$ isomorphic?

Tags: group-theory

Let 
\begin{align*}
G=\langle s, t \mid s^4=1, s^2 = t^3 \rangle
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
G'=\langle S, T \mid S^2=1, T^3=1 \rangle
\end{align*}
be two groups. Are these groups isomorphic to each other? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No because $G$ has an element of order $4$ whereas $G'$ has no such element.

Comment: But $s^4=1$ doesn't imply $s $ has order  $4$. I think some more justification is required.

Comment: @ThomasShelby, but $s^2=t^3\neq 1$, so it must be $4$. Also, when you define a group as $\left<s,t\mid s^4=4\right>$ it's implicit that $s$ has order $4$.

Comment: @ThomasShelby: By definition (universal property of a group given by generators and relations), there is a unique homomorphism $\varphi:G\to C_{12}$ such that $\varphi(s)=3$ and $\varphi(t)=2$. Since $\varphi(s^2)=6\ne 0$, $s$ cannot have order $1$ or $2$.

Comment: @user657324: The definition of $G'$ is clear -- it is the group of words made of $S$ and $T$ and their inverses, quotiented by all relations that are provable from $S^2=1$ and $T^3=1$. I don't see how you rule out that it could have an element of order $4$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: the fact that $s^4=1$ and $s^2=t^3$ doesn't implies that $s^4=1$ and $s^p\neq 1$ for $p<4$ ? (also, when we right $\left<s,t\mid s^4,t^10=1\right>$ means that $s$ has order $4$ and $t$ order $10$, no ?

Comment: @user657324: Just because $s^2=t^3$ doesn't in itself mean that the common value of $s^2$ and $t^3$ has to be different from $1$. For example: $\langle a,b\mid a^2=1, b^3=1, ab=1\rangle$ is the trivial group, so actually $a$ and $b$ both have order $1$ rather than $2$ and $3$.

Comment: (It is worth pointing out, before everyone gets carried away, that the statements user657324 have made are correct, its the logic that is being criticised. One way to make the logic formal is to use free products with amalgamation, or actions of the groups on trees. In fact, I do not know of an "easy" way to solve this problem, although presumably one exists.)

Comment: (In particular, $G^{\prime}$ genuinely does not have an element of order $4$.)

Comment: A somewhat different argument, for the isomorphism question, it realizing the groups as PSL2Z and SL2Z, and use that SL2Z is hopfian, and PSL2Z is a quotient but this also takes work if you don't already have these things.

Comment: T he groups have different abelianizations. The first one cyclic of order $12$, and the second one cyclic of order $6$. That's an easy and  elementary calculation.